# Need to prioritize between two $(document).ready functions in two different JS files being called by the same HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML page which includes 2 JavaScript files (in the same order)

```
<script src="../js/common_js/selectStore.js"></script>
<script src="../js/common_js/dashboard.js"></script>
```

> Note: **selectStore.js** is a common JS file throughout the Web App
>   and **dashboard.js** is specific to the HTML page in question.

Both of these script files have $(document).ready as follows

Inside **selectStore.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    requestUserStoreList();
});
```

Inside **dashboard.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    requestDashLaborCost();
});
```

**requestUserStoreList()** gets a list of stores, passes it to another function which then stores the current *storeID* in session storage.

**requestDashLaborCost()** gets the current *storeID* from the session storage to run a 'POST' API.

Currently **requestDashLaborCost()** gets a null value for the
*storeID* as it is executed before the **requestUserStoreList()**.

> My question is how do I make sure that **requestUserStoreList()**
>   executes before **requestDashLaborCost()** on $(document).ready?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you dispatch a custom event when you first function is complete. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you can consolidate both calls in the same .js file one right after the other if you wanted, and they would fire sequentially in the order they're executed.

Comment: Based on what you've said, the code in `selectstore.js` would be processed first and with multiple `document.ready` functions, the order they are registered is the order that they are invoked.

Comment: You may want to use `setTimeout` to delay when the second function is called.

Comment: Harsh, are you able to edit these files? Or can you not change them?

Comment: @Bibberty - Yes I can edit these files as I created them. Also, if I dispatch a custom event when my first function is complete, wouldn't it create problems for other pages which use the same function? please refer to the "Note" above.

Comment: Are there any asynchronous operations involved ... like ajax requests?

Comment: No, the event will not 'harm' existing code. See the demo below.

Comment: @AgileFox - could you give me an example on it?

Comment: To @charlietfl comment, if you are doing async work you will need to dispatch your event when the promise resolves.

Comment: @charlietfl - both of them have ajax requests. the first function calls the list of stores passes it to another function which saves the selected store from the list and saves it as current store in session storage and the second function in question calls the labor data for the current store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how we might use `CustomEvent` to trigger the code in our second script file.

NOTE: because we just need to do work there is no need to pass `detail`.

Obviously snippets do not support two files. But you get the idea.

```js
let myDataValue = 0;

// This is in file one.
function doWorkNumberOne() {
  myDataValue = 10;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  doWorkNumberOne();
  document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('MyCustomEvent'));
});

// This is in file two
function doWorkNumberTwo() {
  console.log(myDataValue);
}

document.addEventListener('MyCustomEvent', () => {
  doWorkNumberTwo();
});
```

If we are doing some `async` work in our first method:

```js
let myDataValue = 0;

// This is in file one.
function doWorkNumberOne() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      myDataValue = 10;
      resolve();
    }, 1500);
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  console.log('this takes 1.5secs');
  // This is Async so we need to raise when done.
  doWorkNumberOne().then(() => {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('MyCustomEvent'));
  });
});

// This is in file two
function doWorkNumberTwo() {
  console.log(myDataValue);
}

document.addEventListener('MyCustomEvent', () => {
  doWorkNumberTwo();
});
```

For documentation on `CustomEvent` see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent

And here is documentation for CustomEvents in jQuery:

https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

Comment: Since using jQuery can use jQuery custom events also. A bit less typing involved

Comment: @charlietfl can do indeed.

Comment: Happy coding !!